# Cancel loading image with universal-image-loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have GridView with remote image in every block. When I scroll it as fast as possible it lags  the first time. After that it has loaded every image and works smoothly. How can I cancel loading image for blocks that went off screen ?

Comment: universal image loader is caching in background

Comment: Yes I know that, I'm not talking about caching. I want to cancel Image loading request.

Comment: If I have grid of 100 images and I do a fast scroll over all of them. Then In 1-2 seconds I have requested to load 100 images. I need to cancel old ones

Comment: Do you use view re-usage in your adapter? Show your `getView()` method code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If You are Using ViewHolder Pattern, UIL Handles it by itself and you Don't need to Cancel Loading Images for blocks that went off screen!

see [this Part of Source Code](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/a67ce9117d3339598146086023d5ae22cfcee4f2/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/DisplayBitmapTask.java)

```
else if (isViewWasReused()) {
        L.d(LOG_TASK_CANCELLED_IMAGEAWARE_REUSED, memoryCacheKey);
        listener.onLoadingCancelled(imageUri, imageAware.getWrappedView());
    }
```

read more about [ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only solution is to load it directly on the view (not into a bitmap), than you can use the cancel command when you load a new image for that same view.

```
public void cancelDisplayTask(ImageAware imageAware)
```

and

```
public void cancelDisplayTask(ImageView imageView)
```

in ImageLoader

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initImageLoader() {
    ImageLoaderExecutor mImageExecutor = new ImageLoaderExecutor(cpuCount, cpuCount, 0L,    
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LIFOLinkedBlockingDeque());

    // create a ImageLoaderConfiguration instance
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).diskCacheFileCount(500)
            .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).threadPoolSize(cpuCount)      
            .taskExecutor(mImageExecutor)     // set the executor
            .build();
    // init with config
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

this is my custom ImageLoaderExecutor class :

```
import android.os.Process;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * 自定义的图片下载 Executor, 可以取消所有已经加入队列的任务.
 * Created by mrsimple on 4/11/16.
 */
public class ImageLoaderExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private List<Future> mTasks = new LinkedList<>();

    public ImageLoaderExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, new ImageLoaderExecutor
                .DefaultThreadFactory(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, "uil-pool-"));
    }

    public ImageLoaderExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);
    }

    public ImageLoaderExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
    }

    public ImageLoaderExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,
                               RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        Future<?> future = super.submit(task);
        mTasks.add(future);
        return future;
    }


    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        Future<T> future = super.submit(task);
        mTasks.add(future);
        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
        Future<T> future = super.submit(task, result);
        mTasks.add(future);
        return future;
    }

    /**
     * 在 ImageLoader中将使用 execute函数提交任务, 在此我们将 Runnable包装为 FutureTask,
     * 使得离线下载时图片的下载可以取消.
     * @param command
     */
    @Override
    public void execute(final Runnable command) {
        Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                command.run();
                return null;
            }
        } ;
        FutureTask<Void> future = new FutureTask<>(callable) ;
        mTasks.add(future) ;
        super.execute(future);
    }

    /**
     * cancel all task in the list
     */
    public void cancelAllTask() {
        try {
            for (Future f : mTasks) {
                f.cancel(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
        private final ThreadGroup group;
        private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
        private final String namePrefix;
        private final int threadPriority;

        public DefaultThreadFactory(int threadPriority, String threadNamePrefix) {
            this.threadPriority = threadPriority;
            this.group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
            this.namePrefix = threadNamePrefix + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-thread-";
        }

        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(this.group, r, this.namePrefix + this.threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0L);
            if (t.isDaemon()) {
                t.setDaemon(false);
            }

            t.setPriority(this.threadPriority);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should custom a Executor, and then set the Executor to the  ImageLoaderConfiguration instance. The code should like above.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't really much point - by the time your cancel code has finished executing, the image will probably be loaded anyway, and if it's not being used then the garbage collector will deal with it

Comment: not if you load lots and lots of images (scroll down fast), the loading of the image might even not have started yet when you cancel it.